# How can I get if a RecyclerView will use more than one line?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Good afternoon.

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `ConstraintLayout`. The `RecyclerView` receives a number of items that can vary.

How can I find out, for comparison, when the `RecycerView` exceeds the screen width to put an expand button or not?

With a `GridLayout` I have figured it out using `.spanCount`. Another option that I have used is `val column: Int = (view.layoutParams as GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams).spanIndex`, but this does not work for me in the case of the `RecyclerView` within the `Constraint`.

Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your recyclerView vertical or horizontal?

Comment: Horizontal :) I'm thinking on cast to Flexbox and try with flexLines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I tried that but it didn't work for me. At the moment, what is working for me is:

```
  private fun showOrHideExpandIcon() {
    recyclerView.layoutManager = FlexboxLayoutManager(context)
    recyclerView.consumeViewTreeObserver {
      val rows = (recyclerView.layoutManager as? FlexboxLayoutManager)?.flexLinesInternal?.size
      if (rows != null) {
        if (rows == 1) {
          iconImageView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The consumeViewTreeObserver function is a Global Observer created elsewhere so that resources are not used until they are loaded.

Still, I would be interested to know if there is a way to count for the Linear Layout if you use more than one line

Comment: This is not an answer. Update the question with relevant new info.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
if (recyclerView.canScrollHorizontally(-1)) {
    // Show expand button
} else {
    // Hide expand button
}
```

Here, if you give negative parameter to canScrollHorizontally() it means check if it scrolls left side, positive parameter means right side

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but it didn't work for me

Comment: Oh i see, misunderstood... We can override the method canScrollHorizontally()  to enable/disable scrolling in the specified direction